# How to overcome Replace String Error with RegEx Replacement

Tags: regex, vb.net

Below is my code

```
Dim ATT As String = "Hi Sample $1$ Text"
Dim newText As String = "<ss>Hello How Are you</ss>"
newText = Regex.Replace(newText, "<ss>(.*?)</ss>", ATT, RegexOptions.IgnoreCase)
```

The above Code Treats the string content  ("$1$") in ATT variable as Regex value and replaces it in the newText variable, how to overcome this, please guide,

Is there any thing available like we have in perl mentioned below to overcome this problem,

```
$_=~ s/<ss>(.*?)</ss>/\Q$ATT\E/g;
```

Comment: This is vast Coding, with lots of Variables like I mentioned, Is there a way to do it globally, like I posted the code in Perl??

Answer (score 2):

You can either [escape](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/az24scfc.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396#substitutions) the `$` characters in the replacement string:

```
Dim ATT As String = "Hi Sample $1$ Text"
ATT = ATT.Replace("$", "$$")
Dim newText As String = "<ss>Hello How Are you</ss>"
newText = Regex.Replace(newText, "<ss>(.*?)</ss>", ATT, RegexOptions.IgnoreCase)
```

Or use a lambda for the replacement:

```
Dim ATT As String = "Hi Sample $1$ Text"
Dim newText As String = "<ss>Hello How Are you</ss>"
newText = Regex.Replace(newText, "<ss>(.*?)</ss>", Function(m) ATT, RegexOptions.IgnoreCase)
```

Comment: where is the Function (M) :-)

Comment: That's a [lambda](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb531253.aspx)... Maybe I got the syntax wrong, I'm not a VB user ;)

Comment: This is not the solution I am expecting, I already know this to replace $ and use it, but i have 100's of variables like ATT, can't replace and revert for all those things

Comment: So don't change `ATT`, do it like this: `Regex.Replace(newText, "<ss>(.*?)</ss>", ATT.Replace("$", "$$"), RegexOptions.IgnoreCase)`